# Android listview item not showing selected color

Tags: android, android-listview, colors

I have this list view:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/contactsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchButton"
            android:divider="@color/DarkGoldenrod"
            android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

This is the code for the `list_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myRedColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myBlueColor" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myGreenColor"/>

</selector>
```

In my main activity class I have put the following:

```
contactsView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                arg1.setSelected(true);
                selectedContactIndex = (int) arg3;
            }
        });
```

`contactsView` is the list view, and I have confirmed that it IS being selected but the color is not staying. I click it and it changes then changes back. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"` in ListView use it as background in row.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can do on this way also on the layout in which u have your listview set the background of the layout

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

And then in your activity

```
ListView.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey how about adding these lines also to the selector you have made: (if it helps)

```
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myBlueColor" android:state_active="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myBlueColor" android:state_selected="true"/>
```